# How can I use my Icon in Serenity Template instead of Glyphicons?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Serenity template for my asp net MVC application. What I am trying to do is to add icons and use them instead of using serenity template glyphicons. 
I don't know how to do this in this template file.

Answer (score 1):

The icons you use should be font based.

If you need images, match them some class, e.g. my-custom-icon1, then style it with css .my-custom-icon1 { background-image: url(...); )